# 80's techno thriller where Soviets have a control room calculating the odds of 'winning' a nuclear war, and automatically launch above a threshold?

Tags: identification-request

The KGB has a plan to explode a nuclear bomb in the Puget Sound that will have a signature similar to what would be in a U.S. nuclear submarine based there, it will appear to be an accident and eventually result in unilateral disarmament.

I think there was a compromised southern U.S. politician, and a scene where the the hero and love interest evade Migs out of Cuba by flying close to the water in a Cessna.

This was a novel I read in the early or mid 1990s in the U.S. It was probably less than a decade old (therefore '80s') with a present day setting. No cover details. Probably U.S. protagonist, and author. It was not short, probably 400-500 pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my school book report about this: it's [First Strike](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1559741.First_Strike) by [Douglas Terman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Terman) (and on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0684163837) but no good synopsis- maybe I should type up mine)- I didn't mention the scene with escaping the Cuban jets in my write-up, but it definitely has a KGB plot like described above, and a senator under their control who would run for president on a disarmament platform.

The first strike threshold is called the Eighty-Nine-Percent-Level, or ENPL.

[image]

Possibly from the back of the book:

> Hired as a pilot by an ambitious senator, ex-combat fighter Brian Loss finds himself drawn deeper and deeper into international espionage activities that are leading inexorably to World War III.

or according to [google books](https://books.google.com/books/about/First_Strike.html?id=A_gOAQAAMAAJ&source=kp_book_description):

> At an underground factory in Siberia, the Russians have made a replica of a U.S. Navy warhead. Soviet military planners review their ability to survive all-out nuclear war. The KGB selects as its target for high-level political subversion a vulnerable U.S. senator with presidential ambitions.